# can't use FileOpenPicker in uwp c# .net core, any alternative ways to upload pictures in uwp?

Tags: c#, image-processing, file-upload, uwp, fileopenpicker

I wan't to create a photo uploading method for my uwp app but there is no way to do it because I can't use FileOpenPicker or any of the other pickers! It cannot find FileOpenPicker, even if declared like Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
It complains about the type or namespace Windows not being found.
Even when I put `using Windows.Storage.Pickers;` at the top of the file
I have installed NuGet UwpDesktop-Updated to no avail. This is strange because I have been googling for days without finding anyone else with my issue!

Are there any other ways to upload a photo in uwp with c# .net core?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Image.ViewModels;
namespace Image.Views
{
    public partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage(MainViewModel viewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = viewModel;
        }

        private async void Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
            picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

            Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {
                // Application now has read/write access to the picked file
                this.textBlock.Text = "Picked photo: " + file.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                this.textBlock.Text = "Operation cancelled.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe in detail how you created the project? Is the creation process the same as in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-hello-world-app-xaml-universal#step-1-create-a-new-project-in-visual-studio)? 
In addition, you could check whether your Windows 10 SDK is installed correctly with Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: thanks for the reply!
I created a windows template studio (universal studio), then chose mvvm basic instead of codebehind

Comment: Is your question solved? Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: nope, I just gave up. nothing i could find except come to the realisation that uwp is useless and definitely not for the future

Comment: Logically, there is nothing wrong with your code. Could you please provide us a [mcve] by OneDrive or GitHub for testing?

Answer (score 0):

For desktop apps, you need to use the [`IInitializeWithWindow` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-iinitializewithwindow#when-to-use). Or you could just use the pickers built-in to WPF.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to reply and helping a java refugee in the weird world of windows programming